# visual basic two combo boxes

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-express

I'm currently doing a project in Visual express 2013,in VB,and my project is about lfight reservation and schedule.I'm fine with other parts of my coding  but when it comes to the origin and destination,I just cannot seem to find an answer.I used two combo boxes,both have the same items in it

```
eg:
(
Penang(PEN)
Phuket(PHU)
Batam(btm)
koh Samui(USM)
)
```

but I cannot set the destination combobox to only show certain destination when I pick a certain origin.I've searched the Internet,and I could not understand when people say about database,SQL,etc..I really appreciate any help given,or critics

Comment: show some code for better resolution !!

Comment: That's the problem,I don't know the codes to do what I just said.

Comment: have you tried anything yet ??

Comment: take a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959390/populate-2nd-dropdown-by-first-dropdown-value-in-asp-net-vb

Comment: So far,I've tried cmbOrigin.listindex=cmbDest.listindex but it's not working.I've also tried cmbDest.item.add but that only adds the items,not changing the content based of my choice.

Comment: ok thanks for the link,I'll see what I can learn from that.Thumbs up.Btw when I use VS express my tabs is in .vb      is that vb.net?Im still new to this

Comment: 4 questions, 13 answers and you havent accepted any of them

Comment: Ouch,that hurts in a lot of places..Sorry I really forgot to pick my answers.Well,lesson learnt.Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and what you've tried, it's difficult to be certain whether you're talking about determining what items are included in the list, or determining what item is selected without changing the list. I think you mean the former, in which case you need to first clear the list (Items.Clear), and then add the items you want (Items.Add).

Comment: So you are saying that for example I pick "penang" in origin,and I don't want "penang" in destination,I have to clear the list first and add items?so if I have 13 locations each with different amount of destinations,I have to do it all?I don't mind doing that,as long as it is the best way